# Unresolved function or method map() in JSX in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a variable `cartProducts` that comes from the redux state. It's either empty or has some items.
But I don't know why it doesn't recognize the map method on the `cartProducts` when it has some items.

**However, it shows mapped items in output and works, but why does it give this warning?**

Warning's text is `Unresolved function or method map()`

```
export const CartList = ({showCart}) => {
    const cartProducts = useSelector(state => state.cart);
    return(
        <div className={showCart ? "open-list" : "close-list"}>
            {cartProducts.length === 0 ?
                <span>empty</span> :
                <ul>
                    {cartProducts.map((item, index) => {
                      return(
                          <li key={index}>{item.shortName}</li>
                      )
                    }
                    )}
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you using typescript? useSelector would return an object of any type. may be when assigning you can define it as an array.

const cartProducts: CartProduct[] = useSelector(state => state.cart);

Comment: @sanurah Yes, I do. It's installed globally. But anyway, it's an array, although it has type any and it has to accept a map method. Since I worked with the map method in my other projects and I doesn't get a warning like this.